# Sorting in PostgreSQL with UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, redhat, postgresql-9.4

I have a funny sorting problem with a UTF-8 database in PostgreSQL 9.4

My DB settings are:

```
Collation   en_US.utf8
Character type  en_US.utf8
Encoding    UTF8
```

I create a simple table with one text column:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable
(
  testfield character varying(333) COLLATE pg_catalog."en_US.utf8"
);
```

I insert data:

```
insert into testtable values('bla,')
insert into testtable values('bla.')
insert into testtable values('bla f')
insert into testtable values('bla, f')
insert into testtable values('blaf.')
```

I select the data ordered:

```
select * from testtable order by testfield asc
```

I get this wrong order:

```
'bla,'     <--
'bla.'
'bla f'
'bla, f'   <--
'blaf.'
```

When I use:

```
select * from testtable order by convert_to(testfield, 'UTF-8') asc
```

It is right:

```
'bla f'
'bla,'     <--
'bla, f'   <--
'bla.'
'blaf.'
```

Does anybody know why?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Postgres uses the collaction (and thus the sort) support from the operating system.

Comment: PostgreSQL is installed on a Linux
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Oracle Linux Server release 6.5
OL-6.5.1-64